# Neo4j cypher query doesn't return the results as expected into pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to pass on the parameter to the cypher query in a function but it is not returning the results as expected. First error was `ClientError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing} {message: Expected parameter(s): x}` I checked it on another forum where I also had to pass the parameter along with query run session I did so and error disappeared but still it didn't get the results as expected and returned the empty nodes.

In the graph db the nodes are connected with 4 types of relationships with an ids.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
def get_objects(x):
    query = ''' MATCH (p)-[r]->(a) where r.id = $x RETURN p.id; ''' 
    resultNodes = session.run(query, x = x)
    df = DataFrame(resultNodes)
    print(df)
    return df

def find_max_1():
    authors,terms,venues,papers=0,0,0,0
    authors=get_objects(1).max()
    terms=get_objects(2).max()
    venues=get_objects(3).max()
    papers=get_objects(4).max()
    return authors,terms,venues,papers

def main():
    
    m = m=find_max_1()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    main()
```

and the output is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

I am unable to identify what's wrong with this.

Any kind of help in right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you run  `MATCH (p)-[r]->(a) where r.id = 1 RETURN p.id` outside of python?

Comment: yes i tried to run on neo4j browser and it does return the results, the only problem i am facing when passing the parameter to the cypher query in python.

Comment: What happens if you try with 
`query = ''' MATCH (p)-[r]->(a) where r.id="$x" RETURN p.id; '''`

Comment: The other thing that might be worth a try is omitting the semicolon, that might not return the results because it's ready for the next query

Comment: Does it work if you replace the parameter with an absolute value? As in replace the $x with 1?

Comment: There does seem to be an issue with the graph based parameterization. It might be that you have to format the query before passing it to run. Which is a bit disgusting but seems to be a current work around. I don't know if there is an open issue for the parameterization of graph.run queries

Comment: @jhylands yes i tried giving an absolute value as  { ''' MATCH (p)-[r]->(a) where r.id = '1' RETURN p.id  ''' }  and it worked! and semicolon doesn't appeared to be an issue. Also tried {query = ''' MATCH (p)-[r]->(a) where r.id="$x" RETURN p.id;} didn't work

Comment: As bad as it is I think the solution is to pre-format the query string

Comment: it worked if i pass the value as a string, the only thing i dont understand now in to the cypher query x is resolved as int or string? any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't like that this seems to be the best solution it should solve the issue you are having:

```
def get_objects(x):
    query = ''' MATCH (p)-[r]->(a) where r.id = {} RETURN p.id; '''.format(int(x))
    resultNodes = session.run(query)
    df = DataFrame(resultNodes)
    print(df)
    return df

def find_max_1():
    authors,terms,venues,papers=0,0,0,0
    authors=get_objects(1).max()
    terms=get_objects(2).max()
    venues=get_objects(3).max()
    papers=get_objects(4).max()
    return authors,terms,venues,papers

def main():
    
    m = m=find_max_1()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    main()
```

I've added the casting of x to an int to try and provide some added injection security. I believe there is a function for the sanitisation of queries in the library somewhere.

Comment: you sure this is the valid syntax? although I tried it to format x other way separately and then passed it to the function and it didn't work, only empty results.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me.  When you pass integer to the parameter, it will be passed as integer, if string then string.  Moreover, to convert the result into a dataframe, you need to get the values per record and keys as column names.  See below.

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from pandas import DataFrame

x = 88888
query = ''' MATCH (p)-[r]->(a) where r.id = $x RETURN p.id; '''

driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "*****"))
session = driver.session()
result = session.run(query, x=x)

#below is important !!!
rows  = [r.values() for r in result]
cols = result.keys()

df = DataFrame(data=rows, columns=cols)
print(df)
session.close()
driver.close()

Result:
         m.ID
0   987654321
```